# How to pass a list of elements in form with different names to controller using ajax in asp.net core?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to pass groups of radio buttons to controller by AJAX.
This is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.Entities.Questions.Question>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowQuestions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var QuestionCount = 1;
    var i = 1;
 }
<form id="QuestionsForm" method="post">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
            <p>
                <!--choice-->

                @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
                {
                    foreach (var correct in item.choiceQuestionSelection.Where(q => q.QuestionId == 
                  item.QuestionId && q.IsTrue == true).Select(q => q.Choice))
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" data-correct="@i" value="@correct" />
                    }
                    @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
                    {
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group@(i)" class="group" 
                     value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                        </label>
                    }

                    i++;

                }
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    QuestionCount++;

}
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="ارسال">
 </form>
```

this is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public string SubmitAnswers(UserAnswersViewModel userAnswers)
    {
        return "success";
    }
```

this is ajax:

```
$('#QuestionsForm').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this);
  
        $.ajax({
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            method: "POST",
            data: frm.serialize() ,

        }).done(function (res) {
           alert(res)
        });

    });
```

this is the UserAnswersViewModel:

```
 public class UserAnswersViewModel
{
    public List<int> QId { get; set; }
    public List<string> group { get; set; }     
}
```

EDIT:
this is my question model:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }//1
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal Grade { get; set; }

    #region relations
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual IdentityUser IdentityUser { get; set; }
    public Exam exam { get; set; }
    public List<ChoiceQuestionSelection> choiceQuestionSelection { get; set; 
      }
       public List<TrueFalseQuestion> trueFalseQuestions { get; set; }

      #endregion
     }
```

I know each element in my form has different names like:group1,group2,etc.
I don't know how should I get the answers in controller by dynamic names. When I run this it returns null.I searched a lot but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Can you share your Question model?

Comment: I edited the post. please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,you need to change `var i=1` to `var i=0`.And then you need to change the name of input to `group[@i]` and add hidden input of QId as the following:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Question>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ShowQuestions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var QuestionCount = 1;
    var i = 0;
}
<form id="QuestionsForm" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <p>
        <!--choice-->

        @if (item.choiceQuestionSelection.Any(q => q.QuestionId == item.QuestionId))
        {
            <input hidden name="QId[@i]" value="@item.QuestionId" />
            foreach (var correct in item.choiceQuestionSelection.Where(q => q.QuestionId ==
          item.QuestionId && q.IsTrue == true).Select(q => q.Choice))
            {
                <input type="hidden" data-correct="@i" value="@correct" />

            }
            @foreach (var choice in item.choiceQuestionSelection)
            {
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" data-choice="@i" name="group[@i]" class="group"
                           value="@choice.Choice">@choice.Choice
                    </label>
                }

            i++;

        }
    </p>
        QuestionCount++;

    }
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="ارسال">
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked. Can you please explain why should I name the elements like that and why should I start from i=0?

Comment: Firstly,i=0 is because you need to bind a list,index of list starts from 0.And then,.net core bind models with name.If you want to bind list,it's name needs to be like xx[number].